# YouTube iOS Player Helper

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to use the iOS Player Helper to embed YouTube videos in my app but I'm having an issue when the view loads. I used the walkthrough on their site, here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

I get this error in the console:

```
Received error rendering template: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 258.)"
```

Answer (score 3):

I also got same problem with 258 code error. But I got the solution, I missed YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html add to bundle. It is available in youtube-ios-player-helper/Assets/YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html

[error 258 while integrate youtube api helper in to iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212348/error-258-while-integrate-youtube-api-helper-in-to-ios/24214936#24214936)

Comment: I have added that html file too in my app, still i am getting the same error.