# error 258 while integrate youtube api helper in to iOS

Tags: ios, youtube-api

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

I have integrated above youtube helper for ios as per supplied tutorial but I could not able to play video. Following error occur during load the view on Viewcontroller in iOS 7

Received error rendering template: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 258.)"

git source examples also not compiling. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the solution, I missed `YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html` `file` to `add` into `bundle`. It is available in [this link](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/tree/master/Assets)

Comment: I've add the html file as a bundle resource already and still getting the same error. Any tips to solve it?

Comment: Just check your path of file into bundle.

Comment: @Manoj  I am using swift...and manually install library... as said in manual guide. i copy folders and files with checkmark of `copy if needed` and `references` but it gives me error unable to find `YTPlayerView.h` in my bridging-header file....then i'll try to install it without `copy if needed` and `references`...and the error resolved but i got the error #258 when playing the video...i gave a path like....  `let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("YTPlayerView-iframe-player", ofType: "html") `  but it wont work ...so how to resolve this

Comment: The link is broken. I would really like to have this link, plz :(